# what is the best way of running testNG in visual studio code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I love vscode and quite recently I am trying to run some java based code in vscode. Apart from usuall java runner extension, I am struggling to run testNG(along with maven) based tests scenarios in VS Code(i am comparing with something like eclipse).

Did anyone has tried this?
Can you please elaborate the process to make it simple?

Comment: you could refer to this:https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test

Comment: What's the gap prevents you using vscode to run testng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the popular "Java Test Runner" plugin for VsCode at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test --works great!

Answer (score 0):

Since VSCode, I assume, has no TestNG plugin, you're best option in my opinion is using the Gradle TestNG plugin.   That is just my opinion, and you'll find that these sorts of questions are generally not appreciated on Stack sites because they generally generate opinionated answers.

Comment: generate opinions? please elaborate?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201994/is-there-a-place-to-ask-opinion-based-questions

Comment: I mean I know that stack is not for opinion based questions. I meant to ask how my question is asking for an opinion?? I am genuinly looking for best case solutions to run testng based test cases in vs code and that's it. I am not asking if you consider any IDE best or not. Still I think i should have posted as "a way" instead of asking as a "best way", I am considering it and will keep this in mind to avoid giving an opinion based impressions. Thanks